# TCP Dump command for capturing only from 2 specific interfaces

Tags: tcpdump

Is there any commands or possibilities to use TCP dump command to listen from only **2 specific interfaces simultaneously** as something like below, **(instead of using "any" option)**

> tcpdump -i wlan0 AND -i eth0

or

> tcpdump -i wlan0 eth0

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/805022

Comment: Just in case you're not confined to using `tcpdump`, `tshark` supports specifying multiple interfaces, e.g., `tshark -i wlan0 -i eth0`.  From the `tshark` man page (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html): *"This option can occur multiple times. When capturing from multiple interfaces, the capture file will be saved in pcapng format."*